# What is Effective Wingspan?

Tags: wing, winglets

what is Effective wingspan and why it is said ground effect increase "effective wingspan" of an aircraft? Why would vortex affected by surface result in an increase of "effective wingspan" and lift generation?
[image]

Comment: As you see on your figure, you get airlift on the entire "effective wing span", so larger surface. So you get some extra "virtual wing".

Comment: Related, with Peter's doubt that "effective wingspan" works:  https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/35069/how-do-hoerner-wingtips-work