# How does downwash bend airflow down? How can wing-tip vortices reach the airflow in front of the wing?

Tags: aerodynamics, wing, drag, wing-tip-vortex

Wing-tip vortices only start occurring when the pressure difference on the two sides of the wing starts. Wouldn't this mean that by the time the downwash from the vortices is acting on the airflow it would already have bent on to the surface of the wing and could not be pushed down any more?
[image]

In this picture you can see that the flow is already on the wing and it can not bend down any further because the wing is there.

How do the vortices change the direction of the relative airflow before it reaches the wing? The vortices only occur on the wing so they should not be able to do this.

EDIT:
When I say downwash I am talking about wing-tip vortices pushing the airflow down therefore reducing angle of attack.

Comment: Sorry about my bad drawing skills. It is hard to draw with a mouse

Comment: "How does downwash bend airflow down?" it's unclear to me what you are asking. the downwash IS the "bent" airflow.

Comment: What is bending the airflow down if the downwash is the bent down airflow

Comment: the wing is bending the airflow, that's its job.

Comment: When I say downwash I am talking about the downwash that is caused from the down stroke of a wingtip vortex. The downwash that bends airflow down more then normal and causes a wing to be flown at a high angle of attack to maintain height. I will edit my question

Comment: If you use a drawing program, you can add text in the drawing. Built-in ones are Paint for Windows, Preview.for MacOS, and there's a whole array of free apps available. Also, it is good practice to upvote answers that are useful to you. The best one is usually Accepted.

Comment: There is no bending from the wing *and additional* bending from wingtip vortices. Rather, there is bending and *that is* the vortex. See also [How does an aircraft form wake turbulence?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/8882/524) and maybe also [Is induced drag not caused by tip vortices?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/32997/524) and the links therein.

Comment: Try drawing with pen and paper and make a photo. Drawing with a mouse is a terrible idea.